# How do I make a UI button follow a 2d game object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

new to unity and have stumbled into a problem. I am unsure about how to make a UI button on a canvas follow a rigidbody game object in the 2D screen space. I want to make the button's x and y position match the x and y of the RB, so that in theory if I clicked on the RB it would activate the button. However, I am unsure how to implement such a thing into my project.

I tried using transform.position and just equating the ui button pos and RB pos together but it remained static. However, I did script the RB to move to a designated x point and only then did the button move as well despite the RB moving beforehand.

Comment: You could just register the mouse click on the object itself... ;)

Comment: I'll try to hack up some example code tomorrow, but you're looking for something like ```Camera.WorldToScreenPoint()``` (or thereabouts) and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is literally the example in the documentation for [`Camera.WorldToScreenPoint()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html).  Attach this script to your button:

```
public class ObjectFollow : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform Follow;

    private Camera MainCamera;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        MainCamera = Camera.main;    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var screenPos = MainCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(Follow.position);

        transform.position = screenPos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an Idea To Implement that You can use a world space canvas and as a child of that object "that you mentioned has rigid body " now when it moves the canvas and its content will move watch this to 
[Understand Canvas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OD-p1eMsyrU)

Now press on your object at hierarchy window  *Right Click* then **UI** then **Button** 
this will create new canvas and attach button to will look like this 
[hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gePsI.png)

Now Select Canvas and reset its *width* and *height* , set *scale* to small value 0.01 ,0.01 0.01 for example

then change its **Rendering Mode** to Space World and assign camera

> you should insure that you have **event system** it should created automatically but events will never work if you don't have a one in hierarchy Window

---

canvas will like this
[Canvas Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwNLy.png)
Now You can Select this Button and add a function to call using onClick or you can pass it to another script to add this function dynamically like this
[Add Event to UI Button From Script](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html)